# CakePHP asset_compress breaks on css @media

Tags: php, css, cakephp, yui-compressor

In my CakePHP project I'm using plugin asset_compress to compress my css files.

When I use the osx's terminal to compress the files, the final compressed file seems to be missing data from the line where the first @media tag appears.

I have tried CssMinFilter and YuiCss and both return the same result so I'm guessing the problem is in asset_compress.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: please describe your question properly.....